# Making a Node JS web app use https via Elastic Beanstalk and Certificate Manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb, aws-certificate-manager

I'm pretty new to AWS, but I hosted my MERN stack application via Elastic Beanstalk and added in the SSL certificate to the classic load balancer.

The steps I took are below:-

**1) Successfully launch MERN Stack application via Elastic Beanstalk**

**2) Issue an SSL certificate with Certificate Manager**
[image]

**3) Add an SSL port at 443 to my Classic Load Balancer**
[image]

I found all of these instructions via [this blog](https://medium.com/@jameshamann/configuring-your-elastic-beanstalk-app-for-ssl-9065ca091f49) and found similar(the same) advice on the aws docs as well, but my site is still insecure..

[image]

Any pointers on what I may be missing out? I was looking into configuring things with `.ebextensions`, but I'm scared of breaking things irrevocably because the site is currently live.
[image]

Thanks a ton for your help!

Comment: What happens if access your site with https:// instead of http:// ?

Comment: Oh cool, it works! For https://www.ashcodes.com, it works, but for https://ashcodes.com I get a not secure message

Comment: I have two ssl certificates registered (one for www.ashcodes.com and ashcodes.com, while the other uses a wildcard, aka *.ashcodes.com) but the one with the wildcard is connected to the load balancer

Comment: As long as you have a wildcard ssl you can use that anywhere; no need to use separate certificates; since it works you need to find a way to redirect http traffic to https

Comment: gotcha, thanks a bunch for pointing that out!  would I need to use aliases to do this?

Comment: That Ido not know but probably you might find hints in aws docs or something like that

Comment: I’ve added a short answer as well, see if it’s allright

Comment: It's great, thanks! If you do have some info on rerouting http to https, please let me know!

Comment: This might be of help: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably SSL has been enabled but you’re still accessing your website via http://. Try to access it with https:// and most probably it will work. If that’s the case, you need to redirect your HTTP traffic to HTTPS